# Find all values of JQuery Array which is LIKE a string

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to filter an array and find all values which are LIKE the string using JQuery.

Suppose string

```
str = "01.01"
```

Array of values

```
arr = ["01.03","01.01.01","02.01","01.01.02", "01.01"]
```

When I compare the string and array of values in JQuery, how to filter only the following values?

```
"01.01", "01.01.01", "01.01.02"
```

The logic is find all values which are starting with "str" value

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: If I use JQuery.inArray(), I will be able to find only the matching values but not all values matching/starting with that string. if(jQuery.inArray(str, arr) >= 0){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> find all values which are starting with "str" value

Simple solution using `Array.prototype.filter()` and `String.prototype.indexOf()` functions:

```js
var str= "01.01",
    arr = ["01.03","01.01.01","02.01","01.01.02", "01.01"],
    filtered = arr.filter(function (s) {
        return s.indexOf(str) === 0;
    });

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()` method:

```js
var str= "01.01",
    arr = ["01.03","01.01.01","02.01","01.01.02", "01.01"];

var newArr = arr.filter(function(val){
   return val.indexOf(str) !== -1;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: This will also return `"this string which does not match the requirement 01.01"`

Comment: `"01.01", "01.01.01", "01.01.02"` i suppose this is the expectation and it does it. @Andreas. Or am i missing something?

Comment: Just test your solution with the string I mentioned in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Array.filter` function, Like this:

```
function matchString(value) {
    return value.indexOf("01.01") == 0;
}

var filtered = [ "01.03","01.01.01","02.01","01.01.02", "01.01" ].filter(matchString);
```